# Nodejs clustering application cause of connection not stable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm implementing my nodejs server application with `cluster`, after successful this implementation my connection on android is not stable and reconnect every call sockets such as `login`, before implementation i don't have any problem and work fine

```
var cluster = require('cluster'), _portSocket = 3000, _portRedis = 6379, _HostRedis = 'localhost';

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var server                                                = require('http').createServer(),
        socketIO = require('socket.io').listen(server), redis = require('socket.io-redis');

    socketIO.adapter(redis({host: _HostRedis, port: _portRedis}));
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        if (!worker.suicide) {
            cluster.fork();
        }
    });
}

if (cluster.isWorker) {

    var http = require('http');

    http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;

    var socket      = require('socket.io')(3000),
        express     = require('express'),
        app         = express(),
        server      = require('http').createServer(app),
        io          = socket.listen(server),
        mysql       = require('mysql'),
        multer      = require('multer'),
        uuid        = require('node-uuid'),
        datetime    = require('node-datetime'),
        moment      = require('moment'),
        bcrypt      = require('bcrypt'),
        request     = require('request'),
        redis       = require("redis-node"),
        redisIo     = require('socket.io-redis'),
        email       = require("emailjs"),
        redisClient = redis.createClient(),

    var connection =
            mysql.createConnection(
                {
                    host              : 'localhost',
                    user              : 'root',
                    password          : 'a',
                    database          : 'shoot',
                    multipleStatements: true
                });

    socket.adapter(redisIo({host: _HostRedis, port: _portRedis}));

    socket.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, pseudo) {

        socket.on('login', function (data) {
            console.log(data.username);
            login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
               if (success)
                   redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
               socket.emit('login', {result: success, id: value});
            });
        });

        socket.on('userConnected', function (data) {
            ...
        });

    });
}


function formatDate(date) {
    ...
}

function login(username, password, callback) {
    ...
}

...
```

after call `login` socket i dont see any log and doesnt work that and cause of reconnect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved, i posted this problem of solution to anybody want to implementing this feature:

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    mysql       = require('mysql'),
    multer      = require('multer'),
    uuid        = require('node-uuid'),
    datetime    = require('node-datetime'),
    moment      = require('moment'),
    bcrypt      = require('bcrypt'),
    async       = require('async'),
    promise     = require('bluebird'),
    request     = require('request'),
    redis       = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient();

require('sticky-socket-cluster/replace-console')();

var options = {
    workers     : require('os').cpus().length,
    first_port  : 8000,
    proxy_port  : 3000,
    session_hash: function (req, res) {
        return req.connection.remoteAddress;
    },

    no_sockets: false
};

require('sticky-socket-cluster')(options, start);

function start(port) {
    var express = require('express');
    var http    = require('http');
    var app     = express();
    var server  = http.Server(app);
    var socket  = require('socket.io')(server);

    socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            ...
        });

        ...
    });

    server.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Express and socket.io listening on port ' + port);
    });
}
```